# How do I check if a variable is declared in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know that if a variable is declared it is easy to test whether or not it is null, but I can't find a way to work out if a variable is declared at all. What I need is:

If variable is declared:

```
var i:Int
if [i is declared] {
  // returns true
}
```

If variable is not declared:

```
if [i is declared] {
   // returns false (but does not crash)
}
```

Use case: I am writing an app to teach people Swift. I want to be able to evaluate their code and make sure it is correct. So my instruction might be 'create a variable called i and set it equal to 1' and I want to test if they have done that correctly. In PHP I can do isset($i), I need an equivalent in Swift. I can't use if i == null because as simpleBob says that will crash if is not defined.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: In Swift, you cannot use a variable that wasn't declared (it would not compile, you'd get `Use of unresolved identifier 'i'`). Can you be more specific about how your code would look like?

Comment: Why do you need this? What're you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks guys. I am writing an app to teach people Swift. I want to be able to evaluate their code and make sure it is correct. So my instruction might be 'create a variable called i and set it equal to 1' and I want to test if they have done that correctly. In PHP I can do isset($i), I need an equivalent in Swift. I can't use if i == null because as simpleBob says that will crash if is not defined.

Answer (score -2):

If you are just looking to see if there is a variable by a certain name in a class, you could simply start typing the variable name in that class and it should auto-populate.

However, as simpleBob mentioned, the code will not compile if variables are used before their declaration.

**Updated**

I am not sure how you have the users entering data, however, if they are entering it into a UITextView, you could grab the .containsString property and see if they put in the variable as you asked.

```
if myTextView.text.containsString("var i = 1")
    {
        print("They entered it correctly.")
    }
    else
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

You could even chain those to include other variations they would use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is not what I'm asking though. I've clarified the question.

Comment: @user2428168 quick question.  How are you evaluating the users?  Will they be typing into a UITextView?

Comment: Thanks - again though this won't work as the users won't necessarily enter var i = 1 - they might enter var i=1 for example. I could look up every possible case, or strip spaces etc. but this would be very messy. They are actually entering the swift code via a browser window and it is being processed server-side. It looks like it's impossible to tell if a variable has been created in Swift?

Comment: @user2428168 Sorry it wouldn't work, I'm out of ideas.  I hope you get it figured out and if you do, update it here, I'd like to know!  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Matthew! The best solution I got was to do something like var newvar = Int(i). If i doesn't exist the script will crash, so that tells me that the user hasn't defined i correctly. Hard to believe there's no isset equivalent in Swift but it looks like that's the case. Thanks for the help!